# SSRS report change date based on subscription

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to set two different dates for the same `SSRS` report.

What the report basically does is check a `StartDate` and `EndDate` these dates are default to yesterday. 
But I have to implement a new subscription which has to look to the beginning of the month.

I've been investigating and I couldn't see any configuration rather than change the default date, but this will break the first subscription.

I'm thinking to add a boolean flag saying "check from the first" and an `if` inside the `SQL` query.

but I would like to know if there is any better approach rather than this "hardcoded" and ugly way, using the subscription if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a data-driven subscription to calculate the parameter values for the new subscription you want to create. Write a SQL query that gets the two date values you want to use. Then you can pass these in to override the defaults. You don't even have to edit the report and it will be dynamic.